# VB.NET Database Check for Duplicate before submission

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I've been asked to update a legacy VB.net application and while I have part of it done, I am having difficulty implementing a validation check to make sure a row doesn't exist before adding it to a database table. Below is the code I have. I thought I had it working, but it just passes through to my else statement. I want to pass two values from drop down list to parameters and then check if a row exist with those parameters in the specified column.

```
Private Sub joinValidation(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("System_Configuration").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 1 FROM Join_Connection WHERE Alias1ID = @Alias1Check AND Alias2ID = @Alias2Check"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alias1Check", Datasource1.SelectedValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alias2Check", Datasource2.SelectedValue)
            cmd.Connection.Open()
            Dim exists As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
            If exists = "1" Then
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('This Alias already exists in the Alias table.');</script>")
                cmd.Connection.Close()
            ElseIf exists = "0" Then
                addJoin()
                joinResetPage()
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I'm not very familiar with VB.NET so any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: and what is the value of `exists` when you set a breakpoint before your if statement?

Comment: WHen I start the page IISExpress starts, I can add rows to the database from the page, but the breakpoint isn't stopping when the IF statement is hit or before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code it may be help you :

```
 Private Sub joinValidation(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("System_Configuration").ConnectionString)
            Using cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()

                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(1) FROM Join_Connection WHERE Alias1ID = @Alias1Check AND Alias2ID = @Alias2Check"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alias1Check", Datasource1.SelectedValue)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alias2Check", Datasource2.SelectedValue)
                cmd.Connection.Open()
                Dim exists As Integer = 0
                Integer.TryParse(Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar()), exists)
                If exists > 0 Then
                    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('This Alias already exists in the Alias table.');</script>")
                    cmd.Connection.Close()
                Else
                    addJoin()
                    joinResetPage()
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: I had seen the scalar sample I used above in other samples. I like the count and integer way of doing this though. Thanks.

Comment: It is possible that between the time frame of checking and inserting, the same value is inserted.